# Facing issue in laravel orderby

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am facing a issue with laravel order by function.
i want to fetch the records according to country and the result should start from the current user's country.

For example.
if auth user belong to india then list should start from india.

My Current code is

```
$users = User::where('status', '=',1)->with(['profile'])->latest()->orderBy('last_login', 'desc')->paginate(12);
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: @NitishKumar Question updated

Comment: What is `last_login`? Is it attribute of users table?

Comment: yes is attribute of users table

Comment: Country is in profile table

Comment: Use `DB::getQueryLog()` and see what query you're generating. Run that in MySQL interface. See, what error you're getting. And what are you trying to do with **with()**?

Comment: what's the issue, what error? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you get any error?

Comment: No there is no error. i don't know how to fetch record according to preferred country order

Comment: You can't use this format: `latest()->orderBy('last_login', 'desc')`, instead it will be like `latest('last_login')`.

Comment: Share your DB Architecture

Comment: please check db structure
https://screenshots.firefox.com/VaxIADeu5hWwZCyI/localhost

Comment: my current query is 
select * from `users` where `status` = ? order by `last_login` desc

Answer (score 0):

Ok, whatever I've understood, you are looking to sort the data through the `country` attributes from `profiles` table, which is in relation with `User` model, for this you need to use `join` I'm not sure about your structure so I'm just giving you an example. Suppose you want to sort by `profiles` => `id` then you can write something:

**Edit:** As per the requirement given in comments I would recommend to have something like this:
First of all lets have authenticated user by

```
$AuthUser = Auth::user();
```

Then lets call the relation

```
$users = User::->leftJoinRelations('profile')
    ->orderByRaw("FIELD(country , ". $AuthUser->profile->country ."), ASC")
    ->paginate();
```

So in this way you can have user sorted by authenticated user country. Hope this helps.

Comment: plzz check DB Structure
https://screenshots.firefox.com/VaxIADeu5hWwZCyI/localhost

Comment: I don't want to sort by country. i want to show that record first which are same as tha auth User.
For example if Auth::user belong to india then all records from table should start from india

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show the complete structure for profiles table. Also kindly provide complete details. We can't help you with incomplete details.

Comment: @NitishKumar Its not working. i also applied this for a simple table. it show syntax error near country .

Comment: Problem solved By this Code.
`DB::raw("CASE WHEN country LIKE 'india%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, country_name")`